# How can I use a custom(canvas) view two times in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have a custom view made with Canvas class and I am using it in my activity

```
<package_name.view_name
...
view_attributes
...
/>
```

Now I want to use the same view at two places in the same XML file. Can I do it or do I have to create another custom view with same functionality?

Comment: How do you use two `<Button>`s in a layout? Or two `<TextView>`s? Same thing with your custom `View`.

Comment: Because canvas has onDraw() method, which will be called again and again, so was thinking that will there be any bad impact on that or not?